# Formatting mili seconds in java using only hundredth and tenth position of the mill seconds

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i m trying to format timing in mm:ss:MsMs using below code but the code gives me all the three position of mili seconds MsMsMs anyway.
what i get:
00:05:231
what i want:
00:05:23

```
   milliseconds = (int) (appCurrentTime % 1000);

    time.setText(String.format("%02d", mins) + ":" +String.format("%02d", secs) + ":" + String.format("%02d", milliseconds));
```

if i try "appCurrentTime % 100" it will give me ones and tenth digit position where as i need hundredth and tenth position.
from:
00:05:231
what i get:
00:05:31
what i want:
00:05:23

Comment: I don't see how you are calculing `mins` and `secs` here... please provide some reproductible. Have you thought about `DateFormatter` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   milliseconds = (int) (appCurrentTime % 1000);

            String hours,
            minutes=String.format("%02d", mins),
            seconds=String.format("%02d", secs),
            miliSeconds=String.format("%03d", milliseconds);

            time.setText(minutes + ":" + seconds+ ":" + miliSeconds.substring(0,2) );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach you can follow if you have a java.util.Date object.

```
Date d = new Date();
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss:").format(d)+String.format("%.2s", new SimpleDateFormat("SS").format(d)));
```

If you have the milliseconds variable available through other means, you can use the below to print 100th and 10th positions.

```
System.out.println(milliseconds/10);
```

Comment: I would remove the last character of the String to only have 2 digit for milliseoncds but this works too (I don't know a way to limit the digits directly)

Comment: From SimpleDateFormat docs, its minimum number of digits, but it does not provide a limit on maximum number of digits - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html - For formatting, the number of pattern letters is the minimum number of digits, and shorter numbers are zero-padded to this amount. For parsing, the number of pattern letters is ignored unless it's needed to separate two adjacent fields.